# How to get rails config.cache_store config in a Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So, I'm developing my first gem that needs some real connection with rails. It needs to know what is configured into config.cache_store. How do I get this info?

A little more background about it: it's a memcached manager(compatible only with Dalli gem, on it's first version) like resque-web for resque. I've tried reading resque code and it's case is different as it has a initializer for it and the Redis config is loaded from a yml file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config.cache_store is loaded into two different places:

```
Rails.cache
ActionController::Base.cache_store
```

...which are both defaulted from config.cache_store, but can optionally be configured separately.  You should be able to inspect one/both of these depending on what you need to determine the cache config at runtime.

Comment: thanks... I feel so dumb, didn't think of the most obvious solution haha.